# Bootstrap 3.3.5 glyphicon issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have this code:

```
<p>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
    The Old Steam House, Unit 10, Goblands Farm, Cemetery Lane, Hadlow, Kent, TN11 0LT
</p>
```

Which outputs like this, which is fine.
[image]

However, on a mobile it looks like this

[image]

How/what is the best way to indent the text all the way down like this
[image]

I apologise if this isn't a good question to ask, i've never used Bootstrap before.

Comment: This is not something bootstrap solves. Why don't you just use padding-left on the the "p" tag, and set its value based on the the glyphicon's size ?

Comment: Ugh simple fixes, of course

Comment: @elad.chen - I am confused, how `paddin-left` on the p tag fixing the issue here ?

Comment: I was slightly off. What I meant was he could wrap the text in a another container, and give the parent element a padding-left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative left margin on the glyphicon should work.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.multiline-margin {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.multiline-margin > .glyphicon {
    margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="multiline-margin">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
  The Old Steam House, Unit 10, Goblands Farm, Cemetery Lane, Hadlow, Kent, TN11 0LT
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like i said in the comment, bootstrap doesn't solve such cases.

What you can do is use padding-left: [value] where value is the font-size + the spacing you want.

HTML ( changed "p" since "div" cannot be a child of "p" ):

```
<div>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker pull-left"></span>
    <p class="padded-box">The Old Steam House, Unit 10, Goblands Farm, Cemetery Lane, Hadlow, Kent, TN11 0LT</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* this selector is just for example */
div {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.padded-box {
    padding-left: 23px /* 18px + 5px for spacing */ 
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dkcw54wy/